# Spring How to update database entites from dropdown lists thymeleaf

Tags: spring, hibernate, controller, thymeleaf

So I need to update the entities in my table with the selected values from dropdown lists from thymeleaf.

What I want to do is update the movie column based on the selections from dropdown list. But I have more than one dropdown list for each WeekMovie entity.

I cant figure out how to update them all.

My WeekMovies Class

```
@Entity
public class WeekMovies {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="movie_id")
private Movie movie;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="saloon_id")
private Saloon saloon;

//getter setters.
```

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update",method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String updateweekmovies(Model model){
    List<WeekMovies> weekMoviesList = weekMovieService.findAll();
    List<Movie> movieList= movieService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("weekMovieList",weekMoviesList);
    model.addAttribute("movieList",movieList);


    return "updateweekmovies";

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/update",method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateweekPost(Model model){


    return "updateweekmovies";

}
```

My Thymeleaf

```
div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/week/update}" method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="center-block">
                Update Book Information<span style="font-size: small"> * is a
                        required field</span>
            </legend>
            <!-- category -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="weekmovie">*
                    Category</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">

                <li th:each="weekmovie:${weekMovieList}">
                    <select th:value="${weekmovie.movie}"  id="weekmovie" name="weekmovie" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please
                            select an option...</option>
                        <option th:each="movie:${movieList}" th:value="${movie.id}" th:text="${movie.title}"> </option>

                    </select>
                </li>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update Movie</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the error or problem you are facing? Please update the question with relevant details.

Comment: I want to update the WeekMovies table with selected movies from the movielist. But i have several entities in Weekmovies. In one post operation how can i update all with the selected movies from the dropdown list.